# Display all items of Java list on JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have an array list in which I have 10 names. This array is filled by a Servlet and data sent to a JSP page. In the JSP page, I want to print in the labels which are dynamically added by Javascript i.e. if I have 10 names, 10 labels will be added by Javascript.

The problem is, only last name is printed 10 times in 10 labels. I am not able to understand what is the problem.

```
<%
    List<SetsAndGetsData> list = (ArrayList<SetsAndGetsData>) request.getAttribute("Persons");
    for (SetsAndGetsData t : list) {
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var newTextBoxDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'ALPHA');
    newTextBoxDiv1.after().html('<h1 name="textbox1" >Name:' <%= t.getNames()%> '</h1');
    newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup1");
</script>

<%
    }//loop is ending here
%>
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code on server side? Please be sure that it contains all 10 values. Also share your server side code

Comment: yes there are 10 values . i am sure about it .. problem is only in extracting names ...only last one is printed 10 times

Comment: i think javascript is client side language and executed first and then java( extracting values) is executed but i am not sure

Comment: Corrected grammar to some extent. Improved code formatting.

Comment: You can do this with JSTL without requiring javascript. You shouldn't be using scriptlets anymore, it's outdated.